# (16.10) New Nautilus Copy Indicator is Broken

Tags: nautilus, indicator, gui, unity-dash, notification

I have a problem similar to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1615862
However that bug has been marked as a duplicate to a bug which is not at all my problem, making me think this is a different problem.

I just finished copying some files (at least 5 minutes ago) and my dock still has this ugly thing in it:
[image: nautilus icon with broken progress indicator]

Clicking on the Nautilus icon from the picture above, Nautilus immediately opens and looks like this:
[image: "copied finished" is open before I clicked anything]

This happens every time I copy files, no matter if it's one file or a folder.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make this "Finished Copying" notification go away. Obviously clicking on that checkmark doesn't clear the notification (it does nothing). Navigating to other directories doesn't help, as that small 100% circle button stays, and no matter what I do, the progress bar in the dock is still broken (until an X session restart).

So what is wrong here, or how should I attempt to debug this?

A temporary workaround to bring back the old separate-window copy dialogue would also be appreciated!

EDIT: Bug report is located at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1633732

Comment: If you can reliably duplicate it in 17.04, then try to debug it, and then file a bug with the triage information,

Comment: @user535733 thanks I'll try that first thing tomorrow

Comment: If you click on the white space in your Nautilus window, the copy message will go away.

Comment: @heynnema It collapses into that circle button, yes, but it comes back up every time you'd open a new window.

Comment: Have you restarted your computer to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: @heynnema It resets with an X server / unity restart.

Comment: Please explain in more detail. Where do you see this error/message, after a reboot?

Comment: ps: Are you up with the latest Ubuntu updates?

Comment: @heynnema I've gone through all the obvious solutions like reinstalling and upgrades.

Comment: Hopefully it'll get solved in 17.04.

Comment: UPDATE: Bug report has been filed here, along with upstream: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1633732

Comment: It is still broken on Ubuntu 17.04, Nautilus version 3.20.4.
But according to [this ticket](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773527), it has been fixed in Gnome 3.24

Comment: this is a real PITA -- the behavior is still there in gnome 3.24.2  / ubuntu 17.04 (zesty) -- it's a real usability issue, since it affects keyboard navigation. I can kind of force the in-app "popup" notification to go away by making sure I dismiss it on all windows, open a new window, close that window -- but not reliably (there may be a required delay to wait). 1/2

Comment: ...How to just disable that in-app notification altogether? There's no reason for it. 2/2

Answer (score 2):

I found an ugly way to making it go away but it involves restarting nautilus completely, you have to run `nautilus -q` in a terminal.

It's the closest thing to a workaround I could figure out and you will loose all of your open windows, but that progress bar in alt+tab and in the icos it's really distracting.

Comment: Thanks, it irritated me a lot, but at least I can make it disappear using this method :)

Comment: Or, as another work-around, I stopped using nautilus and mostly use dolphin now instead.  Nautilus is unusable if you do most navigation via keyboard, since you have to click on that notification to make it go away (repeatedly). (Also, unrelated: after upgrade from 16.04 -> 17.04, there's no "alt" access to menu items either -- someone really screwed the pooch on this nautilus release.)