# Copy dialogue box issue in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: gnome, nautilus, desktop-environments

I am relatively new to ubuntu and using Ubuntu 17.04 with Gnome DE. While I am copying the files, it's showing a small window (I don't know what we call that stuff) as in any other OS.
[image]
My problem is that every time I open a 
new window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> the same dialogue box will be there. Can I disable that feature/bug?

Comment: Looks more like some sort of notification window informing you of what has been done.

Comment: This bug should be fixed in newer version (v3.24) of Nautilus: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773527

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(16.10) New Nautilus Copy Indicator is Broken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896643/16-10-new-nautilus-copy-indicator-is-broken)